# How to encode user authentication in a barcode

Tags: authentication, barcode

I'm asked to add the possibility to scan barcode (on a badge) to authenticate users when they log in my app.

In this context, my customer has no standard (he does not use badges for now) but would like to use these same barcodes/badges for other apps.

Of course, it cannot be encoded in 'user/separator/password' way, because that will show the password when scanned in any simple text editor.

So, my question is: is there any standards about that?

Also, I'm not aware that barcode scanners are providing builtin functions for that, but are they?

If none of the above, how could it be done?

Preferably, the barcodes I'd want to use may be 1D barcodes.

The authentication needs to be one step in this context.

I'm coding in C#.

Thanks

Edit, for a precision: some login I've to handle are under LDAP.

Comment: Do you want to scan only the barcode, or enter username/password and scan the barcode in addition to that?

Comment: @MarcBalmer, only scan the barcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hash the password in the barcode:

barcode example:

```
user/password
johndoe/secret
```

with SHA-1 hashing:

```
user/5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8
johndoe/E5E9FA1BA31ECD1AE84F75CAAA474F3A663F05F4
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm in that approach (will UV) but some of the logins are handled by LDAP. And for now I do not know how to handle this approach with LDAP.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to authenticate to LDAP with an already hashed password, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44024874/5691758